# Adding long numbers using strings in C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to make a program that adds very large integers using strings. However, for integers which add to a number less than 7, the output is nonsense and all other sums are 7 lower than the correct output. Can anyone discern what may be causing this? 7 seems like its pulled out of thin air.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 10000

int main(void) {
  char str1[MAX],str2[MAX],strnew[MAX],str[MAX];
  int i,l,count,len1,len2,len,zers,nex,excess=0;

  printf("Enter first number:");
  fgets(str1,MAX,stdin);
  printf("Enter second number:");
  fgets(str2,MAX,stdin);

  len1=strlen(str1);
  len2=strlen(str2);

  if(len1<=len2){
    len=len2;
  }
  else{
    len=len1;
  }

  if(len1<=len2){
    zers=len2-len1;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
      if(i<zers){
        strnew[i]='0';
      }
      else{
        strnew[i]=str1[i-zers];
      }
    }
    strnew[len]='\0';
  }

  if(len2<len1){
    zers=len1-len2;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
      if(i<zers){
        strnew[i]='0';
      }
      else{
        strnew[i]=str2[i-zers];
      }
    }
    strnew[len]='\0';
  }

  for(i=len;i>0;i--){
    if(len1>len2){
      str[i]=(strnew[i-1]-'0'+str1[i-1]-'0'+excess)%10+'0';
      excess=(strnew[i-1]-'0'+str1[i-1]-'0'+excess-(strnew[i-1]-'0'+str1[i-1]-'0'+excess)%10)/10;

    }
    if(len2>=len1){
      str[i]=(strnew[i-1]-'0'+str2[i-1]-'0'+excess)%10+'0';
      excess=(strnew[i-1]-'0'+str2[i-1]-'0'+excess-(strnew[i-1]-'0'+str2[i-1]-'0'+excess)%10)/10;
    }
  }
  str[len]='\0';
  str[0]=excess+'0';
  printf("%s",str);


}
```

Comment: Your code is hard to follow. One reason is formatting, but the other is that your algorithm looks too complicated. I recommend you simplify it and then try to follow it by reading the code and see if you can understand what it's doing without much effort.

Comment: And avoid naming your variable `strnew` because it looks like a `str___` function and there are a bunch of them in [tag:c]. Instead it looks more logical to use something such as `sum` or `result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *first* problem lies here:

```
fgets(str1,MAX,stdin);
```

If you enter `27` there, your string buffer will contain `"27\n"`, *with* the newline character.

Since you don't want to do anything with that newline, you should set the lengths accordingly:

```
len1 = strlen(str1) - 1;
```

---

Secondly, you can save a whole lot of `if` statements by just making the strings the same length as early as possible:

```
if (len1 < len2) {
    strcpy(str, str1);
    memset(str1, '0', len2 - len1);
    strcpy(&(str1[len2 - len1]), str);
    len1 = len2;
} else if (len1 > len2) {
    strcpy(str, str2);
    memset(str2, '0', len1 - len2);
    strcpy(&(str2[len1 - len2]), str);
    len2 = len1;
}
```

Once that's done, you no longer need to worry about which is the longer, and your code can be much simpler.

Then it's just a matter of (as you have done) starting at the right, adding each digit, and storing the result. You just have to make sure you leave room for the final carry (excess in your original parlance).

Your code already does this but, as suggested, it can be greatly simplified due to the work done up front to get the numbers to the same length.

The final complete code is below, with an extra check to ensure input is all numeric, an adjustment to get rid of a zero final carry, and with a lot fewer variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 10000

int main(void) {
    char str1[MAX], str2[MAX], str[MAX];

    printf("Enter first number  : ");
    fgets(str1, MAX, stdin);

    printf("Enter second number : ");
    fgets(str2, MAX, stdin);

    int len1 = strlen(str1) - 1;
    int len2 = strlen(str2) - 1;

    // Get both to same length quickly. We'll only use
    // len1 after that.

    if (len1 < len2) {
        strcpy(str, str1);
        memset(str1, '0', len2 - len1);
        strcpy(&(str1[len2 - len1]), str);
        len1 = len2;
    } else if (len1 > len2) {
        strcpy(str, str2);
        memset(str2, '0', len1 - len2);
        strcpy(&(str2[len1 - len2]), str);
    }

    // Now just start at right and do it digit by digit,
    // leaving room for final carry.

    int carry = 0;
    str[len1 + 1] = '\0';

    for (int i = len1; i > 0; --i) {
        // Catch any input problems.

        if (! ( isdigit(str1[i-1]) && isdigit(str2[i-1]))) {
            printf("*** ERROR: Non-digit character in number\n");
            return -1;
        }

        // Work out digit and new carry.

        int newDigit = str1[i-1] - '0' + str2[i-1] - '0' + carry;
        carry = newDigit / 10;
        newDigit = newDigit % 10;

        str[i] = newDigit + '0';
    }

    // Insert final carry if non-zero, otherwise safely move
    // all digits left (overlapping memory needs memmove).

    if (carry != 0) {
        str[0] = carry + '0';
    } else {
        memmove(str, &(str[1]), len1 + 1);
    }

    // Output the result.

    printf("The sum is %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After that, they need to change `str[len+1] = '\0';` to ` str[len] = '\0';`, since they move each digit right one in the loop, to make room for an extra digit at the beginning.